# How to know if 2 ASCII created lines in a command prompt has the same length?

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-interface, console-application, command-prompt

Is there a way to know if these 2 lines have the same size in pixels aka length? What code should I use to determine if they have the same length or not?

Just because these perpendicular lines created with ASCII, they differ in length size according to whether they were put next to one another or line by line under each other or not.

[image: H]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.WindowWidth` and `Console.WindowHeight`. Note that these are measured in columns and rows respectively, not pixels necessarily.

[See documentation for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.windowheight?view=net-6.0)